# Microsoft Account Authentication in API App on Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-api-apps

What I'm hoping to accomplish is a connection to Visual Studio Team Services through the Microsoft Account authentication provider. I've been following the documentation here (https://github.com/Azure/azure-content/blob/master/articles/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-connect-to-saas.md) and have a couple problems with the implementation.

They use the Microsoft.Azure.AppService.ApiApps.Service package to get to the token from the api gateway

```
// Retrieve the token from the gateway
        var runtime = Runtime.FromAppSettings(Request);
        var dropboxTokenResult = await runtime.CurrentUser.GetRawTokenAsync("dropbox");
```

But when I publish my webapp I get a 500 error when trying to create the Runtime object, the remote Debugger literally just dies on the line below and I don't even see any logs in the api's streaming logs interface to give more info on the error.

```
var runtime = Runtime.FromAppSettings(Request);
```

Any idea on how to get to the token?

Documenation for implementing microsoftaccount authentication with a web api is kinda scarce, any links to examples or documentation that was helpful to you guys out there?

Also, is the apiapp.json file really even necessary? They create one in the example but authentication setup Via the Azure blades seems to work ok and leaving the apiapp.json file out of the api doesn't seem to matter either way. In the end I'd like my web api to maintain authentication via microsoft account no matter where it's moved to, so I figured there would be settings somewhere I would need to specify but can't really put that piece together either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using the old model for building API apps (which involves a gateway) which has been deprecated. I believe its still supported, but the official way to build API apps has since changed, and you might find it a bit simpler to work with. More information can be found here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-whats-changed/

Documentation for leveraging Microsoft Account authentication is here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-microsoft-authentication/

Once you're all set up, there are a few different ways you can obtain the token. You can find it as an inbound HTTP header (x-ms-token-microsoftaccount-access-token) or you can use the [App Service Server SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/) to obtain it: something alongs the lines of:

```
var creds = await this.User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>(this.Request);
string accessToken = creds.AccessToken;
```

Comment: Thanks, I was definitely using the old model, once I cleaned all that stuff up and rebuilt with the new sdk it all seemed to start working. The only way I could figure out how to get to the token was by taking your suggestion with the headers: Request.Headers.GetValues("x-ms-token...")